# EventKit problems with custom timezone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, eventkit, nstimezone

EKEventEditViewController's datepicker displays incorrect time (with incorrect offset) if I set custom timezone for the app:

```
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:someOtherTimezone]
```

Is this EventKit bug?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will always show the date in the user's local time zone (the one the user picked in the Settings app). This is because the event will be added the the user's calendar, and Apple wants to show it "correctly"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But then the strange thing is why time in datepicker and time label which is updated when you scroll datepicker differs? It's still the same EKEventEditViewController's view, for me it looks very confusing.